# Jmeter How to make counter related to thread number even in the next loop?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, counter, threadgroup

I face an issue currently in Jmeter which Thread number is not related to the counter. for examples we have a thread group configured as 3 threads which will run in 2 loops. We also use a counter from 11 to 13 in the this thread group.

When we run the following happens after the 1st loop:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Thread_Group_Number</td><td>Counter_Value</td><td>Status</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>11</td><td>Still running</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>12</td><td>Finished</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>13</td><td>Finished</td></tr>
</table>
```

Actual status when the 2nd loop starts:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Thread_Group_Number</td><td>Counter_Value</td><td>Status</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>11</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>12</td><td>Running</td></tr>
</table>
```

Desired status when the 2nd loop starts:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Thread_Group_Number</td><td>Counter_Value</td><td>Status</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>12</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>13</td><td>Running</td></tr>
</table>
```

Actual behavior: 
Thread group is configured as follows:
Number of threads: 3
Loop Count: 2
Counter min: 11, max: 13, and increment by 1.

[Screenshot for the actual behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVDe1.png)

I want in Thread 2 Loop 2 Counter value to be 12, Thread 1 Loop 2 Counter value to be 11, and Thread 3 Loop 2 Counter value to be 13. in other terms I want the value of counter in the following loops to be the same as the their values in the first loop at the same thread number.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you add [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element and configure it like:

[image]

You should get the behavior close to the one you expect

[image]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri,

I've updated the post for better understanding. Could you please recheck it and help?